# Raster statistics

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, statistics

In ArcMap, I have a raster layer representing site locations. I derived elevations values for the sites from a DEM. Now want stats on distribution of elevation values at those sites. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [zonal histogram](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000w6000000.htm) for this if you have Saptial Analyst licence. Just make sure that you select a raster size of the size of your DEM, because the default value is often too large.

Comment: +1 I've never seen that tool before but am keen to give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [zonal stats as table](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000w8000000.htm) that will create a suite of basic statistics for your sites. The sites can be vector or raster.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I ended up using Get Raster Properties:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/0017/0017000000m7000000.htm